# Pass a variable from Layout to children in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the following code `

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import LayoutContent from './layout_content';
type Props = {
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[]
}
const Layout = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(countries[0]);
  const country= selected.id
  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar onClick={toggle} sidebar={open} />
     <LayoutContent sidebar={open} countriesWithsrc ={countriesWithsrc}  selected={selected} lected={setSelected} >
      {children}
     </LayoutContent>
    </>
  )
}
export default Layout;
```

`
How do I pass  the variable country from the Layout component to the children  without state management ?.I.e I want to drill it.

Comment: If you don’t want to pass props down recursively then consider `useContext`

Comment: How can I pass It down recursively Terry?

Comment: You don’t want to pass it down recursively that’s the point.

Comment: Maybe that layout takes too much responsibilities

Answer (score 1):

A important detail is that if the children page is rendered on server side , we have the searchParams and params in the props (at least 'til the current version of NextJs 13.2)... for example :

```js
const Page = async ({searchParams, params}: {
    searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined },
    params: {language: string} 
}) => { 
 console.log('current locale:', params.language);
 console.log('your query param:', searchParams['yourParam'])

....

}
```

good look!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any state management you can use [`React.Children`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren). It provides utilities to work with the `children` prop. `React.Children.map` will run a method for every immediate child of the component. You can use [`cloneElement`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/cloneElement) along with that to create a clone of your element by passing in extra properties. Infact you can even modify the children of an element you are cloning, but that is not the ask here.

Do note that context would be the better way to do it.

```
const Layout = ({ children }: Props) => {
....
....
const modifiedChildren = React.Children.map(children, child => {
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, { testProp : 'test' });
    }
    return child;
  });
....
....

return (
    <>
      <Sidebar onClick={toggle} sidebar={open} />
     <LayoutContent sidebar={open} countriesWithsrc ={countriesWithsrc}  selected={selected} lected={setSelected} >
      {modifiedChildren}
     </LayoutContent>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks For the reply ,I am grateful. How can I use it ,for example in the following  component       import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
const ComingSoonCarbon = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
    <div className="flex justify-center font-bold mt-80 text-xl text-[rgb(245,132,38,0.93)]">
      <h1>Development ongoing.Coming soon @2022</h1>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default ComingSoonCarbon

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using React Context API.

First create the context:

```
// context.ts

import { createContext } from "react";

interface LayoutContextProps {
  country: number | undefined; // undefined, because I assume there's no initial value for country
  setCountry?: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>; // You could also pass a setter if needed.
}

export const LayoutContext = createContext<LayoutContextProps>({
  country: undefined, // Based on the assumption that they may be no known initial value.
  setCountry: () => {}, // Assuming you're passing a setter
});
```

Next, wrap your layout with the context and provide the values.

```
// layout.tsx

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { LayoutContext } from "./context";

type Props = {
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
};

const Layout = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(countries[0]);
  const country = selected.id;

  return (
    <LayoutContext.Provider value={{ country }}>
      <Sidebar onClick={toggle} sidebar={open} />
      <LayoutContent
        sidebar={open}
        countriesWithsrc={countriesWithsrc}
        selected={selected}
        lected={setSelected}
      >
        {children}
      </LayoutContent>
    </LayoutContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default Layout;
```

Now, you can access the context values in the layout's children components.

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { LayoutContext } from "./context";

export default function ChildComponent() {
  const { country } = useContext(LayoutContext); // You may need to check if value if not undefined; up to you.

  return <div>Country ID: {country}</div>;
}
```

This is how I usually do this.